# Merging data frames without duplicating rows

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to merge two data frames, but do not want to duplicate rows if there is more than one match. Instead I would like to sum the observations on that day.

> **From ?merge:**  The rows in the two data frames that match on the specified columns are extracted, and joined together. **If there is more than one match, all possible matches contribute one row each.**

Here's some example code:

```
days <- as.data.frame(as.Date(c("2012-1-1", "2012-1-2", "2012-1-3", "2012-1-4")))

names(days) <- "Date"
obs.days <- as.data.frame(as.Date(c("2012-1-2", "2012-1-3", "2012-1-3")))
obs.days$count <- 1
colnames(obs.days) <- c("Date", "Count")
df <- merge(days, obs.days, by.x="Date", by.y="Date", all.x=TRUE)
```

I would like the final data frame to only list 2012-1-3 one time with a count value of 2.

Comment: Is `days` the same as `z.days`? In that case, do you want the final data frame to have 2012-1-{1,2,3,4} with counts {1,2,3,1} ? (Note `obs.days` has 2 lots of `2012-1-3` and `days` has 1)

Comment: Yes, I just edited z.days to days.  Thanks for catching it.  Your answer below has the expected output. I had tried this with reshape, but I guess I need to learn plyr next.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd suggest you merge them and then aggregate them (essentially perform a SUM for each unique `Date`).

```
df <- merge(z.days,obs.days, by.x="Date", by.y="Date", all.x=TRUE)
        Date Count
1 2012-01-01    NA
2 2012-01-02     1
3 2012-01-03     1
4 2012-01-03     1
5 2012-01-04    NA
```

Now to do the merge you could use `aggregate`:

```
df2 <- aggregate(df$Count,list(df$Date),sum)
     Group.1  x
1 2012-01-01 NA
2 2012-01-02  1
3 2012-01-03  2
4 2012-01-04 NA
names(df2)<-names(df)
```

BUT I'd recommend package `plyr`, which is awesome! In particular, function `ddply`.

```
library(plyr)
ddply(df,.(Date),function(x) data.frame(Date=x$Date[1],Count=sum(x$Count)))
        Date Count
1 2012-01-01    NA
2 2012-01-02     1
3 2012-01-03     2
4 2012-01-04    NA
```

The command `ddply(df,.(Date),FUN)` essentially does:

```
for each date in unique(df$Date):
    add to output dataframe FUN( df[df$Date==date,] )
```

So the function I've provided creates a data frame of one row with columns `Date` and `Count`, being the sum of all counts for that date.