# Left Join in R (dplyr) - Too many observations?

Tags: r, merge, dplyr, left-join

I'm using dplyrs left join function in order to match two dataframes.

I have a panel data set A which consists of 4708 rows and 2 columns ID and Name:

```
ID Name
1  Option1
1  Option2
1  Option3
2  Option2
2  Option3
3  Option1
3  Option4
```

My dataset B consists of single definitions and categories for each name column (86 rows):

```
Name        Definition  Category
Option1     Def1         1
Option2     Def2         1
Option3     Def2         2
Option4     Def3         2
```

So in the end I need following data set C which links the columns of B to A:

```
ID Name      Definition   Category
1  Option1   Def1         1
1  Option2   Def2         1
1  Option3   Def2         2
2  Option2   Def2         1
2  Option3   Def2         2
3  Option1   Def1         1
3  Option4   Def3         2
```

I used a left_join command in dplyr to do this:

```
Data C <- left_join(A,B, by="name")
```

However, for some reason I got 5355 rows instead of the original 4708, so rows were some added.  My understanding was that left_join simply assigns the definitions & categories of B to data set A.

Why do I get more rows ? Or are there any other ways to get the desired data frame C?

Comment: Probably related [Why does the result from merge have more rows than original file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24150765/why-does-the-result-from-merge-have-more-rows-than-original-file); [Merging data frames without duplicating rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8828870/merging-data-frames-without-duplicating-rows).

Comment: sounds like multiple matching so `B` has multiple entries to `A$name`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

With `left_join(A, B)` new rows will be added wherever there are multiple rows in `B` for which the key columns (same-name columns by default) match the same, single row in `A`. For example:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- data.frame(col1 = LETTERS[1:4],
                  col2 = 1:4)
df2 <- data.frame(col1 = rep(LETTERS[1:2], 2),
                  col3 = 4:1)

left_join(df1, df2)  # has 6 rows rather than 4
```

Comment: What is the solution for this? You haven't mentioned that.

Comment: Please provide a solution for the same.

Comment: The solution is to eliminate duplicate keys before you do the join.

Answer (score 5):

It's hard to know without seeing your original data, but if data frame B does not contain unique values on the join columns, you will get repeated rows from data frame A whenever this happens. You could try:

```
data_frame_b %>% count(join_col_1, join_col_2)
```

Which will let you know if there are non-unique combinations of the two variables.

Answer (score 1):

More rows may also appear if you have `NA` values in both `A`'s and `B`'s names on which you join. So make sure you exclude those.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar case. As other answers already mentioned, make sure you have unique values in the columns you're joining:

```
df_to_join <- unique(df2)
joined_df <- left_join(df1, df_to_join, by="name")
```